# Is it possible to squash commits without changing the commit's hash?

Tags: git, github, rebase, squash

I forgot to add a file to a commit that I have already pushed and created a pull request for. The pull request got rejected (because of other reasons). I now want to add the missing file to the original commit and then perform the requested changes in a new commit before issuing a new pull request. However, a `git rebase` to squash the commit of the missing file into the old one changes the hash of the commit which leads to strange effects on GitHub. Is there a way to do what I am trying or do I have to let the missing file in its own commit?

I am the only one using my repository. Pull requests are the only reference to other users.

Comment: What are the strange effects you're hoping to avoid?

Comment: The commit I issued the pull request for disappears from my repositories history and can only be reached from the pull request. The date of the commit changes to today. I even got wired diffs when comparing my branch to the upstreams branch.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a strange effect to me at all. You *are* removing the earlier commit (the one from your pull request) from your history, and adding new different one you created today. I'm not sure what behaviour you're expecting, so I don't know how to answer.

Comment: I want to keep everything as it is, but the missing file added to my initial commit.

Comment: See @manojlds's answer: no can do.  It's Git's strongest guarantee, you can edit the history arbitrarily, but everyone will know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer - no, you can't even change the message of a commit without changing its hash, much less adding a file.

Generally, if you have pushed a change to a remote (that others depend on) you don't change the history by doing things like amending and squashing commits.

The ideal approach might be for you to add the file in a separate commit and have that included in the pull request as well.

Comment: If it's a pull request for a separate project, the ideal approach will be whatever approach that separate project prefers. That may be a new commit to add that one file, or that may be an amended commit.